# QTextEdit::adjustSize() not working?

Tags: qt, qtextedit

Setting text for `QTextEdit`:

```
te->setPlainText(“Something”) ;
te->adjustSize();
```

should wrap around “Something” only, instead the `QTextEdit` is expanding to its maximum Width-Height, can’t fix it..
When I select “Something” on run time, only “Something” is highlighted, no added extra white spaces.

**Expectations**: when text is small enough to fit on one Line, the text edit shouldn’t expand in height, when the text needs to wrap, only the extra line width should be added not the maximum width.

if `adjustSize();` is not called, the text will wrap on the width that was set in the .ui in the Creator, won't dynamically expand horizontally nor vertically..

Some Info:

> Horizontal Policy: Expanding
> Vertical Policy : MinimumExpanding
>   minimumSize : 2×22
> maximum Size : 300×100
> lineWrapMode:
>   WidgetWidth

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, looks like there is no easy way to count lines in `QTextEdit`.
`adjustSize()` is made for `QWidget` and is not reimplemented for `QTextEdit`, it is based on `sizeHint()`.
You can use your own method to count lines, f.e.

1. You can use `QFontMetrics` to calculate width of every word in your text
2. You can set height to 22 and increment it until maximumHeight hitted or vertical scrollbar dissapears.
3. You can get some info from sources of `QTextEdit` itself and subclass it, reimplementing something (`adjustSize()`?) there.

Comment: Thank you :) I will try to calculate the width of text and setGeometry for the QTextEdit accordingly.

Comment: Hi, I encountered the same problem. Can you please share solution if it works?